# Firestore: then triggers twice?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a snippet of TypeScript code (I checked the compiled JS: It looks fine) which is used to update the respective document in my subscriptions firestore collection. It's a Firebased function which is called by a Stripe webhook.

```
const setSubscriptionStateByStripeId = (
  suscriptionId: string,
  targetState: Stripe.Subscription.Status,
  stripeSubscription: Stripe.Subscription): Promise<void> => {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {

    functions.logger.info("CHECKPOINT A");
    // CHECK A
    const db = admin.firestore();
    db.collection("subscriptions")
      .doc(suscriptionId)
      .update(
        {
          state: targetState,
          stripeSubscription: stripeSubscription,
        }
      )
      .then(() => {
        functions.logger.info("CHECKPOINT B");
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => {
        reject(new Error("could not set subscription"));
      });
  });
};
```

I would expect for every `CHECKPOINT A` log, exactly one `CHECKPOINT B` log to show up. However, when I filter to **a single** execution, the Firebase function log shows sometimes:

```
CHECKPOINT A
CHECKPOINT B
CHECKPOINT B
```

I guess this is a "it makes perfect sense when you understand it"-situation. Can someone help me to understand?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete minimal code that anyone can use to reproduce the situation, along with the steps you take to trigger it.

Comment: You tagged with `google-cloud-functions`, but neither your code nor your description points to them being relevant. If Cloud Functions are relevant to the problem, please edit your question to show how. If they are not, please remove that tag.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added the helper method that has the error. Frank: isn't Firebase functions just a wrapper around google cloud functions? Thanks Both: I'm honored you've read my question!

Answer (score 2):

That should not happen. I can't think of a case why it should.

Most likely you are not filtering the single execution properly (or the logs are buggy) - sometime when I look into the logs I see the similar thing you are seeing but after better investigation I understand what is happening and that I was wrong. The code is promise which means that `B` can be logged way past the point where `A` is logged and could be mixed with logs from other executions.

I would recommend improving your logs to tie together point A and B with some ID.
Example:

```
const timestamp = new Date().getTime()
functions.logger.log(`CHECKPOINT A ${timestamp }`);

db.collection("subscriptions")
   .where("someIdField", "==", "someId123")
   .get()
   .then((querySnapshot: any) => {
       functions.logger.log(`CHECKPOINT B ${timestamp}`);
   }
```

Also for investigating the logs, don't use the logs viewer on firebase interface, I found that useless. Go to Function Details -> Logs -> View in Logs Explorer.

If it's really happening please try to provide full code (or just Minimal Workable Example) and screenshots from Logs Explorer filtered for single execution ID.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Went  ahead and checked that, BUT looks the same.. It's really strange and remembers me of the C/C++ times where setting bits or memory issues caused unpredictable behaviour.